# sqlite3 select of BIGINT returns engineering representation

Tags: sqlite

I'm using all of the 64 bits in my BIGINT, and came across an issue storing the values in an sqlite3 db. The values seem to store fine, and I can use the original value for updating the records, but I can't get the values out using sqlite3_exec, or the command line sqlite3.

for example:

```
sqlite> create table mytable (bigval BIGINT, test INT);
sqlite> insert into mytable (bigval, test) values (16791083265364386151, 1);
sqlite> update mytable set test=2 where bigval=16791083265364386151;
sqlite> select * from mytable;
1.67910832653644e+19|2
```

how can I force mysql to output the whole int?

--- edit ---

It seems I'm using all 64 bits of an unsigned int. Is there an unsigned BIGINT type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's largest data type is [signed 64-bit integer, or floating-point](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

If you want to store larger numbers exactly, you have to store them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

or cast to long upon poking into sqlite, and back to uint_64 when reading.  This avoids sqlite's conversion to a floating point number for large unsigned numbers.